# Yii: Getting NOW() instead of time, after save model

Tags: php, yii, frameworks

I have code like following

**Controller:**

```
$model->time = new CDbExpression('NOW()');
$model->save();
$this->render('post', array('model'=>$model));
```

**View:**

```
echo $model->time;
```

Output is:

> NOW()

instead of generated time. Is there any simply way to get time of save model without using find() ?

Comment: why dont you use `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` ??

Comment: Different times on server and sql. However problem is already solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [CActiveRecord::refresh()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#refresh-detail)

Comment: The best method to get data generated by sql. It's just I want!

Comment: Note that refresh does use find under the good, so you are doing a DB call when using this

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
$model->time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$model->save();

echo $model->time; // 2014-1-1 16:21:10
```

Comment: Working but the problem is different times in sql and php. Also I will must change code in many places, so I want use sql's time.

Comment: what is the solution on that? different times in sql and php